# How to pass props to nuxt error page with vue router?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I have a nuxt SSR app, and I'm using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make an HTTP request. When I get an error from my server using axios, I want to pass the error message with vue router as props to my error page, which I have set up as nuxt details [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views/#error-page).

I'm currently using the [composition API](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) in my error layout page. How can I pass the error message as props with Vue router to my error page in `/layouts/error.vue` ? I've tried to pass props as such:

```
router.push({ path: '/error', name: 'error', params: {error: error.response.data}})
```

However the `props` object on the error page does not contain the error data. As mentioned above, my error page is using the composition API:

```
import { defineComponent } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
export default defineComponent({
  setup(props) {


    return {
    }
  }
})
```

I've tried this:

```
router.push({ name: 'error', props: { error: error.response.data} });
```

And I've tried this:

```
router.push({ path: '/error', props: { error: error.response.data} });
```

Still, `props` does not have the error data in the error component (`/layouts/error.ts`)

I'm currently using nuxt 2.15.7

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of the response?

Answer (score 2):

Pass data via prop is used when parent component include child component. But, in your case, **router.push** just redirect from this component to other component ( layout error ), so you can not get prop.
You passed error through param of route, it is not good solution. You need State management to store error from fetching data

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Moe. Can you show either documentation or source code that supports your claim? I would like to see either documentation or source code that shows how props data is lost when using `router.push` as a redirect from a page component to a layout component (`/layouts/error.ts`). If you can support your claim with either documentation or source code, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Before explain this problem, i will suggest another solution to pass message to error page : Instead of use router.push , you can use function this.$nuxt.error ( in composition , function error is in context , can access as param of setup(props, { error }) )

this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: error.response.data})

If you use Vue debug on chrome, you can see Error Page is child of Nuxt component. That mean props of Error is passed from Nuxt . When use router.push, Nuxt can not understand your message, but with function error, it can. Hope we can have best solution for this case

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a solution to my problem. However, the solution does not leverage `props` so I will not accept this solution as the answer.

Instead of the error component referencing `props`, it will reference `route`

```
import { defineComponent, useRoute } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
  layout: 'error',
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    console.log('route', route.value.params.error)
    return {};
  },
});
```

Based on [these docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) we see that:

> Note: params are ignored if a path is provided, which is not the case for query, as shown in the example above. Instead, you need
> to provide the name of the route or manually specify the whole path
> with any parameter:

```
const userId = '123'
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId } }) // -> /user/123
```

Based on those docs, my error component should be able to reference errors from `route.value.params.error` if my code routes to the error component as such:

```
router.push({ name: 'error', params: { error: error.response.data } })
```

The above code will work provided that I do not reference `path: '/error'` inside the object which is passed to the `push` api.